# Split List into Given Equal Size X and remaining list should not be less than size Y

Tags: java

For Example :
I have list of 21 Balls and I want to allocate them in Bucket.
Bucket size should be minimum 2 and maximum 5.

```
I want output like 
B1 has 5 Balls
B2 has 5 Balls
B3 has 5 Balls
B4 has 4 Balls
B5 has 2 Balls
```

**That means I want to allocate Buckets to maximum number of balls and then remaining.**
We can take unlimited Buckets.
If possible I want it in JAVA code .
Please help me to find solution
Thank you

Comment: How many buckets? Always 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n/5` will give you the number of buckets of size 5 that will be full.

`n%5` will give you the rest that couln't be placed.

If `n%5 >= 2`, create a new bucket and place those.

If `n%5 = 1`, create a new bucket, add it, and pick one in another bucket.

This example demonstrates the algorithm :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        place(21,5);        
    }

    public static void place(int number, int sizeBucket){
        int nbBuckets = number / sizeBucket;
        int nbLeft = number % sizeBucket;
        List<Bucket> lBuckets = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nbBuckets; i++){
            lBuckets.add(new Bucket(sizeBucket, sizeBucket));
        }       
        if(nbLeft >= 2)
            lBuckets.add(new Bucket(5, nbLeft));
        else if (nbLeft == 1){
            Bucket b = lBuckets.get(lBuckets.size()-1);
            b.setSize(b.getSize()-1);
            lBuckets.add(new Bucket(sizeBucket, nbLeft+1));
        }
        System.out.println(lBuckets);
    }
}

class Bucket {
    private int capacity;
    private int size;

    public Bucket(int capacity, int size) {
        super();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bucket [capacity=" + capacity + ", size=" + size + "]";
    }       
}
```

Output :

```
[Bucket [capacity=5, size=5], Bucket [capacity=5, size=5], Bucket [capacity=5, size=5], Bucket [capacity=5, size=4], Bucket [capacity=5, size=2]]
```

Comment: No of balls, Buckets max and min size may change ?

Comment: @OomphFortuity What do you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

1.Check whether after filling one bucket with 5 balls leaves at least two balls.
2.if not , try with 4 and so and so..till 2. (If it is 2 , That will be your last bucket)
3.Fill one bucket
4.Repeat these steps as long as you have enough balls

Answer (score 0):

*I have designed a generic method for you where u can enter min, max size of balls(for buckets) and total number of balls*

**method to get number of buckets to be created.**

```
long getNoOfBucket(long total, int max, int min) {
        if (total % max < min && total % max != 0) {
            return (total / max) + 1;
        } else {
            return total / max;
        }
```

**method to get list of buckets.**

```
 List<List<Long>> getbucketOfBuckets(long total, int max, int min) {
            List<Long> tempBucket = null;
            List<List<Long>> parentbucket = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();
            if (total % max < min && total % max != 0) {
                long noOfBucket = getNoOfBucket(total, max, min); 
                for (long i = noOfBucket; i >= 1;i--) {
                    if (total % max < min && total % max !=0) {
                        total = total - min;
                        long tempVar = total+1;
                        tempBucket = new ArrayList<Long>();

                        for (long j = 1; j <= min; j++) {

                            tempBucket.add(tempVar);
                            tempVar++;
                        }
                        parentbucket.add(tempBucket);
                    } else {
                        long tempmax = 0;
                        if(total%max == 0){
                            tempmax = max;
                        }else{
                            tempmax = total%max;
                        }
                        total = total - tempmax;
                        long tempVar = total+1;
                        tempBucket = new ArrayList<Long>();
                        for (int j = 1; j <= tempmax; j++) {

                            tempBucket.add(tempVar);
                            tempVar++;
                        }
                        parentbucket.add(tempBucket);
                    }
                }
            }
else{
            for (long i = noOfBucket; i >= 1; i--) {

                total = total - max;
                long tempVar = total + 1;
                tempBucket = new ArrayList<Long>();
                for (int j = 1; j <= max; j++) {

                    tempBucket.add(tempVar);
                    tempVar++;
                }
                parentbucket.add(tempBucket);
            }
            }
            return parentbucket;
```

**main method to test above code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long total = Long.valueOf(args[0]);
    int max = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
    int min = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
    long noOfBucket = BallServicesImplementation.getNoOfBucket(total, max,min);

    List<List<Long>> parentBuclet = BallServicesImplementation.getbucketOfBuckets(total, max, min);
    for(List<Long> itr : parentBuclet){
        System.out.println("size :: "+itr.size());
        for(Long seLong : itr){
            System.out.print(seLong+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("********************************************");
    }
```

I have tested it under different test cases.u may try it and let me know if require some more improvement. 
hope it will help u.